# give direct proof of the fact $a^2 - 5a + 6$ is even for any integer

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I know this is true but I don't know how to prove it.

I have worked it out for the integers from $1$ to $10$ but this is not direct proof, is there a formula I need?

Comment: Do you know modular arithmetic? Or are you trying to solve by induction?

Comment: $a^2-5a+6=(a-2)(a-3)$. Since $a-3$ and $a-2$ are consecutive integers one has to be even.

Comment: I do not know modular arithmetic no sorry

Comment: actually if you are talking about stuff such as 13 mod 12 = 1 then yes i do

Comment: if you are allowed modular arithmetic then $a^2 - 5a + 6$ becomes $a^2 + a$ mod 2.  Since $a^2$ and $a$ are either simultaneously even or simultaneously odd, then their sum must be even.

Comment: $a^2+5a+6 \equiv a^2-a \pmod{2}$ Is this always $0$?

Comment: @fvel: Yes, $a_2-a$ is always zero mod $2$.

Comment: Tom, please do not repost a question, especially one that garnered 7 answers.

Answer (score 0):

$a^2-5a+6=a(a-5)+6$. You can obviously see that $a(a-5)$ is always divisible by $2$, for if $a$ is even then nothing more to prove and if $a$ is odd then $a-5$ is even. So, $a(a-5)$ is even. Also, $6$ is even. So, $a^2-5a+6=a(a-5)+6$ is even.